# How can you use variables defined in node.js in client side js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having problems with using 'pairs' in my java script file, more specifically whenever I run the code pairs is not defined. I have tried everything i can think of and this is what i think should work:

This is my node.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let data = fs.readFileSync('inputs.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');
global.pairs = data;
```

And this is my java script file:

```
console.log(pairs)
```

Obviosly it doesn't work and instead of an array of inputs i get an error. I cannot just do the console.log in node.js because i need the inputs for other things that cannot be done in node. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can print it in the html page, use the script tag with the type="text" so it is invisible to the viewer then parse the content with javascript client side.

Comment: The client-side JS can make an AJAX request to the node.js script, and the variable can be returned in JSON.

Comment: How are you serving your html and js files to the browser, can you post that code as well please? Seems like you should just make the `inputs.txt` available for download (possibly in JSON format) and use it on the client side.

Comment: You should probably call an API for this, and in turn i.e. response will return JSON which should contain that variable's reference. So you can get its value